# Consolidate Rows Using Dictionary In VBA with Sum and Max/Min to certain columns

Tags: arrays, excel, dictionary, vba

I am attempting to consolidate rows of data that share several attributes (e.g. order number and product number).  For example:  Order 12345 has 4 rows of data all with the same product number but each row has a unique revenue amount.

I want to have an end result where all 4 rows are consolidated into 1 row which has the revenue amounts summed from the 4 original lines.  Additionally each row has a start and end date.  I need the final consolidated row to have the earliest (`MIN`) start date and the last (`MAX`) end date as the end result in the consolidated line.

My target lines to be consolidated are not always consecutive in the data and thus I figured a dictionary would be they way to go (in which a unique ID (used to identify lines that need to be consolidated) are my "key").  I found a similar question on here and used code from that answer to get to where I am at now.

I have a "unique ID" which determines what lines need to be consolidated together (if the ID is the same, the lines need to be consolidated). The Unique ID is a concatenation of 4 columns (order #, product, a contract name and state).

My current code is:

```
Dim oRange As Range
Dim oTarget As Range
Dim oRow As Range
Dim oRowAmend As Range
Dim oDic As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim sIndex As String
Dim vKey As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long


Worksheets("ODD Data").Activate

 LastRow = Worksheets("ODD Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  'Define the source range
Set oRange = Sheets("ODD Data").Range("A2:CE" & LastRow)

'Define where the updated data will be printed.
Set oTarget = Sheets("Consolidated ODD Data").Range("A2:CE2")

Set oDic = New Scripting.Dictionary

For Each oRow In oRange.Rows

    'Define Indexes (what is checked for duplicates)

sIndex = oRow.Cells(82) 'Column 82 is my unique ID column 

    'If the index exists, sum the values
    If oDic.Exists(sIndex) Then

        Set oRowAmend = oRow

 oRowAmend.Cells(36).Value = oRow.Cells(36).Value + oRowAmend.Cells(36).Value 'Column 36 is the column which has the revenue amount I wish to sum


        oDic.Remove (sIndex)
        oDic.Add sIndex, oRowAmend

    'If does not exist, only store their values
    Else

        oDic.Add sIndex, oRow

    End If

Next oRow


For Each vKey In oDic

    vItem = oDic.Item(vKey)
    oTarget = vItem

    'Points oTarget for next row
    Set oTarget = oTarget.Offset(1, 0)

Next vKey

End Sub
```

Currently the code runs without error and I get the expected number of lines output onto the new "Consolidated ODD Data" Sheet.  Column AJ (36) is not summing however.  It appears that whatever the value in column AJ is for the last line to be consolidated is simply doubled (not added to the other lines needing to be consolidated).  This is happening not only on the output sheet but ALSO on the original data set (which I do not want).

I have no idea how to apply the MIN / MAX Functionality to my start and end dates.  Any help on this (or any part) is much appreciated.  The start date is in Column O and End Date is in Column P.  All the other columns will be identical between the rows I am consolidating.

I was wondering if I need to story an array as an item in my dictionary?  I am new to this and getting a bit over my head!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the unique key - a concatenation of order and product ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie The Unique ID is a concatenation of 4 columns (order #, product, a contract name and sate)

Comment: You could use an array, but, once you get used to it, it will be easier (and more easy to maintain in the future) to create a User Defined Object (Class), storing the data in the class object and storing that object in the dictionary.  Within the class you can have a method that sums the revenue amount (or whatever else you want to do).  Then you can output the data fairly simply, once it has been collected in the dictionary. See Chip Pearson's [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) to get started.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie 
 
is there a way we can get into the "chat" function of the site? I think your answer is spot on, but I'm having issues understanding how to use the first two sections of code outside of the sub routine. The way I am using it now I get either "invalid attribute in sub or function" OR "user defined type not defined"

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Nevermind - I was able to get the class creation all figured out.  I know this is simple stuff - but could you hint at "printing" the results to a sheet instead of the immediate window?  Also in the immediate window it appears to only be including the key, dates and rev.  When I print to a sheet, I need to keep all the other columns also?

Comment: @RugsKid - see my edit on the question per your comments about printing to another sheet with the additional fields.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I was able to adapt everything just as you described - Thank you very much - One last note: With your loop output to the sheet being to specific cells ie. `wsOutput.Cells(1, 1).Value = objDic(varKey).Order`, the output is currently overwriting itself in row 1.  What method do you suggest to "move the output down a row each time"?

Comment: Hi @RugsKid - see my latest edit for working loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this data in `Sheet1` starting at `A1`:

```
| Row | Key             | Order | Product | Contract | State | Value | Start    | End      |
|-----|-----------------|-------|---------|----------|-------|-------|----------|----------|
| 1   | aaa|123|foo|bar | aaa   | 123     | foo      | bar   | 11    | 27-11-17 | 08-01-18 |
| 2   | bbb|456|foo|bar | bbb   | 456     | foo      | bar   | 11    | 22-11-17 | 23-12-17 |
| 3   | aaa|123|foo|bar | aaa   | 123     | foo      | bar   | 10    | 30-11-17 | 05-01-18 |
| 4   | bbb|456|foo|bar | bbb   | 456     | foo      | bar   | 13    | 03-12-17 | 08-01-18 |
| 5   | aaa|456|foo|bar | aaa   | 456     | foo      | bar   | 27    | 04-12-17 | 24-12-17 |
| 6   | bbb|123|foo|bar | bbb   | 123     | foo      | bar   | 6     | 12-12-17 | 26-12-17 |
| 7   | bbb|123|foo|bar | bbb   | 123     | foo      | bar   | 9     | 10-12-17 | 30-12-17 |
| 8   | bbb|456|foo|bar | bbb   | 456     | foo      | bar   | 11    | 04-12-17 | 06-01-18 |
| 9   | bbb|456|foo|bar | bbb   | 456     | foo      | bar   | 24    | 28-11-17 | 23-12-17 |
| 10  | bbb|456|foo|bar | bbb   | 456     | foo      | bar   | 27    | 26-11-17 | 06-01-18 |
| 11  | aaa|123|foo|bar | aaa   | 123     | foo      | bar   | 3     | 27-11-17 | 07-01-18 |
| 12  | aaa|123|foo|bar | aaa   | 123     | foo      | bar   | 1     | 02-12-17 | 24-12-17 |
| 13  | bbb|456|foo|bar | bbb   | 456     | foo      | bar   | 26    | 01-12-17 | 03-01-18 |
| 14  | aaa|123|foo|bar | aaa   | 123     | foo      | bar   | 26    | 05-12-17 | 31-12-17 |
| 15  | aaa|123|foo|bar | aaa   | 123     | foo      | bar   | 24    | 08-12-17 | 21-12-17 |
```

Where the formula for `Key` is:

```
=C2&"|"&D2&"|"&E2&"|"&F2
```

You are well advised (per @RonRosenfeld) to use a `Class` for the dictionary value, e.g. `Class1` (just create a new class in VB editor) and then enter:

```
Option Explicit

Public ConsolidatedRevenue As Double
Public FirstDate As Date
Public LastDate As Date
```

Then you can use code like this (with intellisense support):

```
Dim obj As Class1
Set obj = New Class1
obj.ConsolidatedRevenue = 99 
obj.ConsolidatedRevenue = obj.ConsolidatedRevenue + 99
```

So, the following code will:

- loop every row
- if the key is not in the dictionary then add the key and a new `Class1` with the data for that row
- if the key is not new, then get the existing data and increment revenue and compare dates to get start and end for the consolidated item

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim varKey As Variant
    Dim dblRevenue As Double
    Dim dtStart As Date
    Dim dtEnd As Date
    Dim objData As Class1

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- change to your worksheet
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A2:I16") '<-- change to your range with last row etc
    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<-- late bound reference to dictionary

    For lngCounter = 1 To rngData.Rows.Count
        varKey = rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 2).Value '<-- the key
        dblRevenue = CDbl(rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 7).Value) '<-- the revenue
        dtStart = CDate(rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 8).Value) '<-- the start date on row
        dtEnd = CDate(rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 9).Value) '<-- the end date on row

        ' test for key in dictionary
        If objDic.Exists(varKey) Then

            ' get existing data packet
            Set objData = objDic(varKey)

            ' increment revenue
            objData.ConsolidatedRevenue = objData.ConsolidatedRevenue + CDbl(rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 7))

            ' update first date if earlier
            If dtStart < objData.FirstDate Then
                objData.FirstDate = dtStart
            End If

            ' update last date if later
            If dtEnd > objData.LastDate Then
                objData.LastDate = dtEnd
            End If

        Else

            ' create a new data packet
            Set objData = New Class1

            ' set properties for new item
            objData.ConsolidatedRevenue = dblRevenue
            objData.FirstDate = dtStart
            objData.LastDate = dtEnd

            ' store new data packet in dictionary
            objDic.Add varKey, objData

        End If
    Next lngCounter

    ' test dictionary
    For Each varKey In objDic.Keys
        ' output could go to another sheet instead of immediate window...
        Debug.Print "Key: " & varKey
        Debug.Print "Revenue: " & objDic(varKey).ConsolidatedRevenue
        Debug.Print "First Date: " & objDic(varKey).FirstDate
        Debug.Print "End Date: " & objDic(varKey).LastDate
    Next varKey

End Sub
```

The output is:

```
Key: aaa|123|foo|bar
Revenue: 75
First Date: 27-Nov-17
End Date: 08-Jan-18
Key: bbb|456|foo|bar
Revenue: 112
First Date: 22-Nov-17
End Date: 08-Jan-18
Key: aaa|456|foo|bar
Revenue: 27
First Date: 04-Dec-17
End Date: 24-Dec-17
Key: bbb|123|foo|bar
Revenue: 15
First Date: 10-Dec-17
End Date: 30-Dec-17
```

You should be able to adapt that to your data set. To do the min/ max tests on the dates the proposed code just uses `<` and `>` between the current dates stored in the data packet (e.g. `Class1` properties) and the dates from the row being processed:

```
' update first date if earlier
If dtStart < objData.FirstDate Then
    objData.FirstDate = dtStart
End If

' update last date if later
If dtEnd > objData.LastDate Then
    objData.LastDate = dtEnd
End If
```

HTH

### Edit

Per the comment question about only printing the key dates and revenue - you can add extra fields to the class:

```
Option Explicit

Public ConsolidatedRevenue As Double
Public FirstDate As Date
Public LastDate As Date
Public Order As String
Public Product As String
Public Contract As String
Public State As String
'... etc
```

Then in the main loop, get those additional values e.g.

```
' ... (Dim them all first e.g. Dim strOrder As String etc)
strOrder = rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 3).Value
strProduct = rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 4).Value
strContract = rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 5).Value
strState = rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 6).Value
' ...
```

And then you can add them to the instance of `Class1`:

```
' ...
objData.Order = strOrder
objData.Product = strProduct
objData.Contract = strContract
objData.State = strState
' ... etc
```

And then when you loop the dictionary you can output them e.g.

```
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output") '<-- change to your output sheet
' loop the dictionary
Dim lng As Long
For lng = 0 To objDic.Count - 1
    ' ... instead of Debug.Print output to sheet with wsOutput.Cells(x, y).Value = foo
    Set objData = objDic.Items()(lng)
    wsOutput.Cells(lng + 1, 1).Value = objData.Order
    wsOutput.Cells(lng + 1, 2).Value = objData.Product
    wsOutput.Cells(lng + 1, 3).Value = objData.Contract
    wsOutput.Cells(lng + 1, 4).Value = objData.State
    wsOutput.Cells(lng + 1, 5).Value = objData.FirstDate
    wsOutput.Cells(lng + 1, 6).Value = objData.LastDate
    wsOutput.Cells(lng + 1, 7).Value = objData.ConsolidatedRevenue
    ' ... etc
Next lng
```